# Postgres 10.3 could not bind IPv6 address, database system was not properly shut down

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am running Postgres v10.3 through Docker (docker-compose, specifically).  It is not turning back on.  I get the following error message when I try to turn it on:

```
postgres           | pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
postgres           | waiting for server to start....2018-05-15 12:37:07.552 UTC [22] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
postgres           | 2018-05-15 12:37:07.552 UTC [22] LOG:  could not bind IPv6 address "::1": Address not available
postgres           | 2018-05-15 12:37:07.552 UTC [22] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
postgres           | 2018-05-15 12:37:07.558 UTC [22] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres           | 2018-05-15 12:37:07.804 UTC [23] LOG:  database system was interrupted while in recovery at 2018-05-15 12:35:58 UTC
postgres           | 2018-05-15 12:37:07.804 UTC [23] HINT:  This probably means that some data is corrupted and you will have to use the last backup for recovery.
postgres           | .........2018-05-15 12:37:17.735 UTC [23] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
postgres           | .2018-05-15 12:37:17.935 UTC [23] LOG:  redo starts at 1/5E964BA8
postgres           | pg_ctl: server did not start in time
postgres           | ................................................. stopped waiting
```

I may have shut down the database as I was writing to it, which is the only thing I can think of that would have caused this.  I do not have a backup which is why I'd like to restore what I've already done (except for the table that I was writing to when I shut down).

Things I've tried:

- Restarting the docker container and clearing out the cache (`docker system prune -f`)
- Remove the `postmaster.pid` file and restarting

  - This gives me a `could not open file "postmaster.pid": No such file or directory` error and generates a `postmaster.pid` file which then allows me to get back to my original error

When running in `single_user_mode` with more logging I get

```
/ $ postgres --single -D /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata -P -d 5
2018-05-15 15:16:09.978 UTC [12] DEBUG:  invoking IpcMemoryCreate(size=148537344)
2018-05-15 15:16:09.978 UTC [12] DEBUG:  mmap(148897792) with MAP_HUGETLB failed, huge pages disabled: Out of memory
2018-05-15 15:16:09.999 UTC [12] DEBUG:  SlruScanDirectory invoking callback on pg_notify/0000
2018-05-15 15:16:09.999 UTC [12] DEBUG:  removing file "pg_notify/0000"
2018-05-15 15:16:10.005 UTC [12] DEBUG:  dynamic shared memory system will support 288 segments
2018-05-15 15:16:10.005 UTC [12] DEBUG:  created dynamic shared memory control segment 262836907 (6928 bytes)
2018-05-15 15:16:10.005 UTC [12] DEBUG:  InitPostgres
2018-05-15 15:16:10.005 UTC [12] DEBUG:  my backend ID is 1
2018-05-15 15:16:10.010 UTC [12] LOG:  database system was shut down in recovery at 2018-05-15 15:16:04 UTC
2018-05-15 15:16:10.014 UTC [12] DEBUG:  checkpoint record is at 1/64CA6F18
2018-05-15 15:16:10.025 UTC [12] DEBUG:  redo record is at 1/5E964BA8; shutdown FALSE
2018-05-15 15:16:10.025 UTC [12] DEBUG:  next transaction ID: 0:681710; next OID: 311511
2018-05-15 15:16:10.025 UTC [12] DEBUG:  next MultiXactId: 155; next MultiXactOffset: 312
2018-05-15 15:16:10.025 UTC [12] DEBUG:  oldest unfrozen transaction ID: 547, in database 1
2018-05-15 15:16:10.025 UTC [12] DEBUG:  oldest MultiXactId: 1, in database 1
2018-05-15 15:16:10.025 UTC [12] DEBUG:  commit timestamp Xid oldest/newest: 0/0
2018-05-15 15:16:10.025 UTC [12] DEBUG:  transaction ID wrap limit is 2147484194, limited by database with OID 1
2018-05-15 15:16:10.025 UTC [12] DEBUG:  MultiXactId wrap limit is 2147483648, limited by database with OID 1
2018-05-15 15:16:10.025 UTC [12] DEBUG:  starting up replication slots
2018-05-15 15:16:10.028 UTC [12] DEBUG:  starting up replication origin progress state
2018-05-15 15:16:10.031 UTC [12] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2018-05-15 15:16:10.037 UTC [12] DEBUG:  resetting unlogged relations: cleanup 1 init 0
2018-05-15 15:16:10.334 UTC [12] LOG:  redo starts at 1/5E964BA8
```

My dockerfile extends this one: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/fe8c9a4a309a889dc057d53bf3769c25c1522c65/10/alpine/Dockerfile

And the entrypoint is changed to be this: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/fe8c9a4a309a889dc057d53bf3769c25c1522c65/10/alpine/docker-entrypoint.sh

And here's the `ifconfig`:

```
MacBook-Pro:backend zebrainatree$ docker-compose demo run postgres ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:AC:12:00:03  
          inet addr:172.18.0.3  Bcast:172.18.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:90 (90.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
ip6tnl0   Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          NOARP  MTU:1452  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
tunl0     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-10-8B-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Comment: > "pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway". Port occupied because already running?

Comment: it's not running elsewhere

Comment: when i pull `postgres:10.3` and do `ifconfig` i dont see any network interface with IPv6, you should provide your Dockerfile and output of ifconfig

Comment: @MazelTov i added that to the question

Comment: I also added more logs

Answer (score 0):

We got it to work by entering the postgres docker container via `bash`, then `su postgres`, and finally `postgres --single -D /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata -P -d 5`

It took about 15 minute from there, but it worked!

Comment: `-d 5` is the debug level, so irrelevant. `-P` is more interesting - do you have corrupted catalog indexes? All in all, I believe you just were patient enough that time to wait for recovery to finish.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything to worry about:

- `could not bind IPv6 address "::1": Address not available`

  That means that `getaddrinfo` returned `::1` as an IP address for `localhost`, but IPv6 is not working.

  Your DNS setup is misconfigured, but it is no big problem — you just cannot connect to the loopback interface with IPv6.
- `waiting for server to start.....stopped waiting`

  Startup took longer than `pg_ctl` cared to wait. Annoying, but no problem per se. See the next point.

  You should always consult the PostgreSQL log in such a case.
- ```
  LOG:  database system was interrupted while in recovery at 2018-05-15 12:35:58 UTC  
  HINT:  This probably means that some data is corrupted and you will have to use the last backup for recovery.
  ```

  This just means you have been impatient and interrupted a previous startup attempt, didn't you?

  The hint is there, because if that happens *without a panicky sysadmin interrupting the startup process*, it probably means that recovery crashed, possibly because of bad data in database files.

15 minutes for crash recovery is not short.

Perhaps there was a lot of activity since the last checkpoint (and `max_wal_size` is set very high), perhaps you got really slow disks, perhaps your restrictive cgroups settings give you too few resources...